# Is there a better way to diff from a patch?

Tags: vimdiff

Background: I'm working on a large project that has some disparate coding styles. I'm working on [unifying that](https://github.com/python/black) but only the parts that I've most recently touched.

The tool that I'm using produces a diff file, so I can do:

```
 black --diff <filename> >/tmp/patch
```

And then

```
 :diffp /tmp/patch
```

Which works great! I can `]c` and `[c` to navigate my changes and `do` to get the ones that I want. The only problem is that I end up with this garbage `myfile.new` living in my pwd.

I couldn't find anything in `:help :diffp` that suggested there was any good way to say, "Okay, I'm done now, go away other file!"

The closest thing I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16679182/344286) - `:call delete(expand('%')) | bdelete!`. This does exactly what I want. I could bind this of course, but I'm wondering...

Is there a better way? Should I just add `nnoremap <leader>rm :call delete(expand('%')) | bdelete!<cr>` or something to `$MYVIMRC`?

Comment: Vim open patched buffer (myfile.new) with notedited flag by default  (check it with `c-g` or `:f`),  it's only a buffer, not a real file yet, did you manually save the file?

Comment: `wa` won't save file which has noteditedflag unless it's modified.